# ImportError: libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, python-3.x, webkit, shared-libraries, pyqt5

Hi I am trying to work with pyqt5 on python 3.

When I import **QWebPage** and **QWebView** from **PyQt5QtWebKitWidgets**
I get error

```
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage, QWebView
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fancybrowser.py", line 49, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage, QWebView
ImportError: libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file:   No such file or directory
```

I am on arch linux and using i3 window manager.
Previously it was working at the time when I was on *GNOME*.

I dont know but may be it has to do something with it.

Also I followed this link:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1655833#p1655833

but it doesnot help me too.

Plese help me to solve this.

Comment: The link seems to provide all the answers you need. Why do you say it doesn't help you?

Comment: I just type those in shell without understanding the things. By following the instruction on the link I need to find the missing dependency and install it. This solved my problem. @ekhumoro2